# jQuery: deleting row in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, datatables

I'm using jquery datatables and I have some `<tr>` inside a table with the following structure:

```
<tr class="odd">
     <td class="  sorting_1">0</td>
     <td class=" ">2011</td>
     <td class=" ">20</td>
     <td class=" ">
         <span class="btn-group">
            <a class="del btn btn-small" href="#"><i class="icon-delete"></i></a>       
         </span>
     </td>
</tr>
```

I writed the following jquery code for deleting the row associated to the button I click on.

```
$(".del").bind("click", function(event){
        var target_row = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
        var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(target_row); // the error occurs here!
        oTable.fnDeleteRow(aPos);
          });
```

but I obtain an error like this:

`"TypeError: a.nodeName is undefined"` in jquery min script file.

**EDIT:**

Here the code for creating datatables:

```
if( $.fn.dataTable ) {
            $(".mws-datatable").dataTable();
            var oTable = $(".mws-datatable-fn").dataTable({
                bRetrieve: true,
            sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
            });
        }
```

Comment: please post whole of your relevant jQuery code :) and try including jquery from Google APIs and see it it works

Comment: What is the logic inside fnGetPosition function?

Comment: I have already tried using Google APIs cdn, but it does not works.
@Hearaman here you can find the logic og fnGetPosition: http://datatables.net/ref#fnGetPosition

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I solved the problem using this code:

```
$(".del").bind( "click", function(event) {
    var target_row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0); // this line did the trick
    var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(target_row); 

    oTable.fnDeleteRow(aPos);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$().ready(function () {
  $('body').on('click', '#deletebtn', function () {
    $("#example1 tr").each(function () {
      var rowSelector = $(this);

      if (rowSelector.find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked')) {
        rowSelector.remove();
      }
    });
  });
});
```